# Solve equation for $x$, why not a closed format?

Tags: proof-verification, polynomials, problem-solving

I am trying to solve for $x$ the following:

$\big(\frac{x-m}{d*x+f}+1\big)^s = \big(\frac{n-m}{d*x+f}+1\big)$

I have tried with `Wolfram Alpha` functionality `Solve` but I didn't obtain anything. Is there a way to solve it or proof that it can not be solved analytically?

Comment: What is the nature of $s$ ? Have you heard of the unsolvability of polynomials ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust s is a positive integer (or a positive real). I heard about it but I would like to know more for this specific case (i.e.: why is it unsolvable ?)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the solutions of equations have no closed form !

Comment: For integer $s$ the equation can be rewritten as a polynomial.